# MobileServiceTable.InsertAsync ZUMO-API-VERSION Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to migration Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Services. In C# I'm using `MobileServiceClient.GetTable` to get a `MobileServiceTable` object. With this I try to insert an object using `MobileServiceTable.InsertAsync`.

After upgrading I am getting the error-

> An invalid API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of 2.0.0

I understand the error, but I don't know how to update the request headers to add this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the SDK.  Remove the WindowsAzure.MobileServices SDK and add the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client SDK.  If you use offline-sync, then replace the equivalent SQLiteStore packages as well.

For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services